# Unpack items and count them with one step

Tags: python-3.x, zip, enumerate

I'm trying to iterate over `X`s and `y`s simultaneously unpacking them and using the `enumerate()` function to count the pairs, as shown the following code:

```
X = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19, 20]]
Y = [[11, 21, 31, 41], [51, 61, 71, 81], [91, 101, 111, 121], [131, 141, 151, 161], [171, 181, 191, 201]]

index = 0
for x, y in zip(X, Y):

    print(f'{index }, {x}, {y}')

    index += 1
```

I'd like to save the `index += 1` line, and be able to get all index, x and y in the for loop

**What I've Tried:**

- I've tried using `enumerate` function on the `zip`, but it requires me to unpack the `x` and `y` manually latter, as shown in the following code, and I'd like to save this line:

```
X = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19, 20]]
Y = [[11, 21, 31, 41], [51, 61, 71, 81], [91, 101, 111, 121], [131, 141, 151, 161], [171, 181, 191, 201]]

for index, data in enumerate(zip(X, Y)):
    x, y = data
    print(f'{index}, {x}, {y}')
```

**Desired Outcome:**

The desired outcome may be seen in the following schematic *pseudo-code*:

```
#for index, x, y in zip(X, Y):
#    print(f'{index }, {x}, {y}')
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can unpack the value returned by `enumerate` straight into the tuple (your pseudo-code just misses the brackets):

```
for index, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(X, Y)):
    print(f'{index}, {x}, {y}')
```

-->

```
0, [1, 2, 3, 4], [11, 21, 31, 41]
1, [5, 6, 7, 8], [51, 61, 71, 81]
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use data[0] and data[1] in f-string. So, you can use less temporary variables.

`for index, data in enumerate(zip(X, Y)): print(f'{index}, {data[0]}, {data[1]}')`